# ElementAPI: Include author/user data with entry?

Tags: plugin-elementapi

Searched around online and couldn't find an answer to this question. I want to be able to include some data from the author/user account associated with an entry.

Here is the basic working version of an individual entry, which does display the 'author' name, but no idea how to display that user's data, such as; profile photo, first name, last name, and custom member fields.

```
'listings/<entryId:\d+>.json' => function($entryId) {
  return [
    'elementType' => 'Entry',
    'criteria' => ['id' => $entryId],
    'first' => true,
    'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
      return [
        (int)$entry->id,
        (int)$entry->year,
        $entry->manufacturer,
        $entry->model,
        $entry->author
      ];
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$entry->author` is going to be a [UserModel](https://craftcms.com/classreference/models/UserModel) object, so you've got access to all of its properties and methods depending on what you need to return.

i.e. `$entry->author->firstName`, `$entry->author->lastName`, etc.

Here's a list of them from a Twig perspective, but the same things are available to PHP. https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/usermodel

Comment: Brilliant! Figures it was way easier than I thought. Thanks Brad! 